# SQL Server : FULL OUTER JOIN unusual behavior

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join, full-outer-join

I have 2 tables. I want to get the records from both the table using `FULL OUTER JOIN` while filtering out some data from one of the tables.

1. 14026 - Total number of common records.
2. 8428 - unique records in table 1
3. 1512 - unique records in table 2.

The total records that I should get are 23966. However, the following queries return different results.

**Query 1** -

```
SELECT DISTINCT pu.id,
       vm.id
FROM table1 vm
FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT pu.id 
                 FROM table2 pu 
                 WHERE pu.column1 = 'filter1'
                 AND pu.column2 = 'filter2') pu ON vm.id = pu.id;
```

Output - 23966 rows (expected).

**Query 2** -

```
SELECT DISTINCT pu.id,
       vm.id
FROM table1 vm
FULL OUTER JOIN table2 pu ON vm.id = pu.id AND pu.column1 = 'filter1' AND pu.column2 = 'filter2';
```

Output - 48804 rows.

**Query 3** -

```
SELECT DISTINCT pu.id,
       vm.id
FROM table1 vm
FULL OUTER JOIN table2 pu ON vm.id = pu.id 
WHERE (pu.column1 = 'filter1' AND pu.column2 = 'filter2')
OR (pu.column1 IS NULL AND pu.column2 IS NULL);
```

Output - 21830.

According to my understanding at least the third query should also give me the same result as query 1. Can someone explain me how SQL Server is treating these 3 queries?

Comment: Your `Where` clause in the 3rd query is changing the `Outer Join` to an `Inner Join`, thus limiting the data.  Those conditions should be in the `Or` clause.

Comment: @Siyual - I thought including `IS NULL` in the `WHERE` clause would not filter out the data that is coming from `table1` but not present in `table2`.

Comment: That is true, but you also have `WHERE (pu.column1 = 'filter1' AND pu.column2 = 'filter2')` in the `Where` clause.  In the first query, these are effectively in the `Outer Join` `On` clause.

Comment: `WHERE` clause is after `full outer join` - from what I understand first join the tables then filter the results using `where` clause.

Comment: @Siyual - When I do an `INNER JOIN` I get a total of 14026 records as mentioned in the question.

Comment: @JHS I don't see anything in the question mentioning an `Inner Join`?

Comment: try to create a simple model, here is a start http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c259a1/4